# I have an Rails APP API with Doorkeeper OAuth2 client_credentials. How to get bearer token information within the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, ruby-on-rails-5, doorkeeper

I have an Rails APP API with Doorkeeper OAuth2 client_credentials. I want to get the token information within the controller and get the uid of the user who consumed the bearer token and send a logger.info to the logs. Seeking your suggestions / ideas in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm̀ not sure if I understood your question correctly but I'll try my best here.

Once you set up your doorkeeper configuration a helper method called [`doorkeeper_token`](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/52dc279d57b647ed51e54167f4e9009316983645/lib/doorkeeper/helpers/controller.rb#L38) will be available in your controller.
This method returns a `Doorkeeper::AccessToken` instance and should have the proper resource owner and application for the issued token.

If you are using the client credentials flow, your issued token will only contain an `application_id` but no `resource_owner_id` (as the resource owner is your user).

To have a resource owner a token has to be issued by the [resource owner password credentials flow](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-flow).

As for the log, you could have a `before_action` in your application_controller (or whatever base controller you use) that calls a method or simply a proc to log the token information:

```
before_action :log_token_info

def log_token_info
  # log user name or whatever attribute you wish
  # for the user id you can simply access the doorkeeper.resource_owner_id
  logger.info "Token resource owner: #{doorkeeper.resource_owner.name}"
end
```

Same goes for the application related to the token